# jQuery stopping $.post proccess after certain time

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I have `$.post()` code and I wanna to pass him after certain time, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set a timeout for your `.post`, you can either change the code to use `.ajax` instead and set the `timeout` option.  Or you can use `.ajaxSetup` and set the `timeout` option.

Note that using `.ajaxSetup` will affect all jquery ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `timeout` parameter you can set: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings   (search for 'timeout').